# MS- Access: Switch or Iif based on count of other query field

Tags: ms-access, count, switch-statement, counter, iif

I am attempting to combine offices into a group called "Other" based on: if the `Count()` of the number of tickets is less than (<) 10.  In my `Branch_Department` table, I have created an entry for "Other" with and ID of 15.

**First attempt:**

```
SELECT Branch_Departments_tbl.Branch_Dept, Count(Accounting_Tickets_tbl.Branch_ID) AS CountOfBranch_ID, Switch([CountOfBranch_ID]<10,'15', [CountOfBranch_ID]>10, [Branch_Departments_tbl]![ID]) AS New_ID
FROM Branch_Departments_tbl INNER JOIN Accounting_Tickets_tbl ON Branch_Departments_tbl.ID = Accounting_Tickets_tbl.Branch_ID
GROUP BY Branch_Departments_tbl.Branch_Dept;
```

When I run this, I get an unexpected prompt to 'Enter Parameter Value' for `CountOfBranch_ID` rather than it using the `Count` logic first.

Also, the `New_ID` field does not change to '15' if the `Count` is less than 10

**Second query attempt:**

```
SELECT Branch_Departments_tbl.Branch_Dept AS [Branch / Dept], Sum(Accounting_Tickets_tbl.[Time Worked]) AS [Total Time Worked], Round(Avg(Accounting_Tickets_tbl.[Time Worked]),2) AS [Average Time Per Ticket]
FROM Submitter_Name_tbl INNER JOIN (Owner_Names_tbl INNER JOIN (Category_tbl INNER JOIN (Branch_Departments_tbl INNER JOIN Accounting_Tickets_tbl ON Branch_Departments_tbl.ID = Accounting_Tickets_tbl.Branch_ID) ON Category_tbl.Cat_ID = Accounting_Tickets_tbl.Category_ID) ON Owner_Names_tbl.Own_ID = Accounting_Tickets_tbl.Owner_ID) ON Submitter_Name_tbl.Submit_ID = Accounting_Tickets_tbl.Submitter_ID
GROUP BY Branch_Departments_tbl.Branch_Dept
HAVING (((Branch_Departments_tbl.Branch_Dept)=IIf([Tickets Per Branch]<10,"Other",[Branch_Departments_tbl]![Branch_Dept])));
```

Again, I get an unexpected prompt to 'Enter Parameter Value' for CountOfBranch_ID rather than it using the `Count` logic first.

And the Name of the branch does not change.

I'm scratching my head over here and would love some insight into my query flaws.